# On expanding Expandable widget the adjacent widget aligns itself too

Tags: flutter

I am  trying to have 2 expandable cards side by side in a row, But when expanding one the other card shifts downwards as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPm4b.jpg).

Could you please help me?... I don't want the other card to shift downwards when the other card expands....

I show my code below:

**The body of scaffold:**

```
enter code herebody: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ExpandableCard(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ExpandableCard(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

**The widget:**

```
class ExpandableCard extends StatelessWidget {

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ExpandableTheme(
      data: const ExpandableThemeData(iconColor: Colors.blue, useInkWell: true),
      child: ExpandableNotifier(
        child: Card(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 200.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black38,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('asset/images/picture.jpeg'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ScrollOnExpand(
                scrollOnExpand: true,
                scrollOnCollapse: false,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black38,
                  child: ExpandablePanel(
                    theme: const ExpandableThemeData(
                      headerAlignment: ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
                      tapBodyToCollapse: true,
                    ),
                    header: Text('Landscape'),
                    collapsed: Text(
                      'Description',
                      softWrap: true,
                      maxLines: 2,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                    expanded: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                            'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    builder: (_, collapsed, expanded) {
                      return Expandable(
                        collapsed: collapsed,
                        expanded: expanded,
                        theme: const ExpandableThemeData(crossFadePoint: 0),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like its because of the Columns default mainAxisAlignment property is center. Try this

```
Column(
mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.start....
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do edit this.

```
   child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          **crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,   //Edit this** 
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ExpandableCard(),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ExpandableCard(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```